# Django form validation on empty IntegerField

Tags: django, django-forms, django-validation

I have a form that I don't render as part of HTML page but validate input against:

```
class milestone_form(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(required=True)
    completion = forms.IntegerField(initial=0, required=False)
    due_date = forms.DateField(required=True,input_formats={'%d.%m.%Y'})
    phase = forms.IntegerField(required=True)
```

this completion bit is causing lots of problems:

```
form = milestone_form(request.POST)
form.is_valid()#will return False on empty completion
```

I tried overriding form's clean() to make completion = 0 when it's empty:

```
def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = self.cleaned_data
    if cleaned_data.get('completion') is None:
        cleaned_data['completion'] = 0
    return cleaned_data
```

However, it doesn't help. Is there something else I'm missing?

Comment: You should include the `input` for completion in the form, but use a `HiddenInput` widget so that it isn't displayed.

Comment: I ran the code you have given and it runs fine for me. Form is reported to be valid when completion is None or not present in POST array. Also trying to change the value of completion in form's clean method is not useful since it is the last function to be called in the chain of validation and cleaning. Have a look at: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/forms/validation/#form-subclasses-and-modifying-field-errors

Comment: it is a real input available for entry - I just want it to be '0' when the field is empty.

Comment: @abhaga, lucky you :) it doesn't run well for me: `<ul class="errorlist"><li>completion<ul class="errorlist"><li>Enter a whole number.</li></ul></li></ul>` although form debug shows `completion = {int} 0`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably the way I'd go about returning an integer for a blank field, with error checking:

```
from django.forms import ValidationError

def clean_completion(self):
    if self.cleaned_data.get('completion'):
        try:
            return int(self.cleaned_data['completion'].strip())
        except ValueError:
            raise ValidationError("Invalid number")
    return 0
```

Comment: clean_completion isn't getting hit though

Comment: if I use this def as field's validator, form will still not be valid and return `enter a whole number` although `completion = {int}0`